# Show Files trough viewmodel isn't possible because of static types cannot be used as type arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I've done a file upload in my wabaplication and I'm making the view that retrieve thos epictures and show them to the user. I use ViewModel  show data to user and I get error when i try to add `List<File>` to the `ViewModel`.

I have the folowing error :

> 'System.IO.File': static types cannot be used as type arguments

on the line of the delcaration of `public List<File> files {get; set;}` on the `ViewModel` class.

Here is my ViewModel

```
    public class AuditAndCritereViewModel {
    public string name {get; set;}
// 10+ another fields
    public List<File> files {get; set;}
    }
public AuditAndCritereViewModel(int auditId)
        {// init fields}
```

Here is my controller:

```
Public Actionresult Get(int id)
{
AuditAndCritereViewModel model = new AuditAndCritereViewModel(id);
return View(model);
}
```

How Can I do to fix the code? Do I have to pass files in `ViewBag` (looks dirty for me because `ViewModel` is already here)

Thanks to help me!

Comment: For the moment I use http://imageresizing.net/download but I wanted to use File to make thumbnails in c#...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is exactly what error say. You can't use static class as property type.
If you really want to set file to ViewModel you should use `FileResult` or `FileContentResult` or just `byte[]`.

Comment: thanks @teovankot! There is no other solutions so I will use this next time :-)